# JavaScript Regex to replace YAML frontmatter

Tags: javascript, regex, yaml-front-matter

I'm building a nodejs package that reads the YAML front matter from a file. I used the YAML package to get the YAML, convert it to JSON and make my changes to it.

Now I want to be able to replace the whole frontmatter but can't find the RegEx to do so.

```js
templateFile = templateFile.replace(SOME-REGEX-EXPRESSION, YAML.stringify(frontmatter)
```

What RegEx can I use here to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

### New answer to modified question

```
/---\n.*?\n---/s
```

This regex matches frontmatter including `---` start and end. Compared to the old regex you just need to not use lookaheads.

### Old answer

You can use this to match frontmatter without `---`:

```
/(?<=---\n).*?(?=\n---)/s
```

Breakdown:

- `(?<=---\n)` - positive lookbehind to match `---` followed by new line
- `.*?` - lazily match anything
- `(?=\n---)` - positive lookahead to match `---` preceded by new line
- `s` - flag for dot to also match new lines

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wb7t1a/1)

Comment: That works great, thank you, but how do I include the `---` in the results as well? It turns out I have to completely replace the Frontmatter block, not the content in the frontmatter block.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted your solution as the correct answer to my question, my apologies for not also upvoting the answer.  I edited the question to reflect the need, can you please help me?

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped me. I realized that I must accommodate Unix and DOS line endings, so that makes the solution `/---[\r\n].*?[\r\n]---/s`